# Define a unique constraint between combinations in 2 columns and a third column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the table below, (colA, colB, colC) is the primary key. In colD, I have defined a new type of id which is unique per (colA,colB) combination, that is:

colD = f(colA,colB)

so that (A,1) should give me id_1, (B,2) corresponds to id_2 etc where the ids are integer values. The table below shows a mistake where for (A,1) there are 2 ids - id_1 and id_2.

I would like to enforce a constraint that each pair of values (colA,colB) maps to one and only one value in colD. Of course, I can add a unique constraint to (colA,colB,colC,colD) because (colA,colB,colC) is the primkey, but this won't detect colC and colD changing simultaneously.

I'm not sure what the best way is here.

```
 +colA + colB + colC + colD +
 +--------------------------+
 | A   |  1   |180901| id_1 |
 | A   |  1   |180902| id_1 |
 | A   |  1   |180903| id_1 |
 | A   |  1   |180904| id_2 |
 | .   |  .   |  .   |  .   |
 | .   |  .   |  .   |  .   |
 | .   |  .   |  .   |  .   |
 |     |      |      |      |
 |     |      |      |      |
 |     |      |      |      |
 |     |      |      |      |
```

Comment: Create a view instead of storing computed values. (Or have a computed column.)

Comment: @jarlh the point is that eventually, primkey will be (colD,colC) and colA, colB will be dropped.

Comment: Why can't you just create a unique index/constraint for (cola, colb, cold)?

Comment: @SalmanA - because in their sample, they have 3 rows with the combination `(A,1,id_1)` and *they want to allow that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce this constraint using an indexed view:

```
create table dbo.T (colA char(1) not null, colB int not null,
colC int not null, colD varchar(6) not null,
constraint PK_T PRIMARY KEY (colA,colB,colC))
go
create view dbo.DRI_T
with schemabinding
as
    select colA,colB,colD,COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
    from dbo.T
    group by colA,colB,colD
go
create unique clustered index IX_DRI_T on dbo.DRI_T (colA,colB)
go
insert into T(colA,colB,colC,colD)
values ('A',1,180901,'id_1')
go
insert into T(colA,colB,colC,colD)
values ('A',1,180902,'id_1')
go
insert into T(colA,colB,colC,colD)
values ('A',1,180903,'id_1')
go
insert into T(colA,colB,colC,colD)
values ('A',1,180904,'id_2')
go
```

The error generated by this fourth insert statement is:

```
Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 23
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.DRI_T' with unique index 'IX_DRI_T'. The duplicate key value is (A, 1).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Hopefully you can see how it's working to achieve this error. Of course, it's not reported exactly the same as a direct constraint violation but I think it contains enough information that I'd be happy using this in one of my DBs.

And you can of course pick far better names for the `DRI_T` and `IX_DRI_T` if you want to make the error more obvious. E.g. `IX_DRI_T_colD_mismatch_colA_colB`

Comment: You can also do this with a function and a check constraint like `alter table t add constraint ck_fn_checkd check (dbo.fn_checkd(a,b) = 1)`.  But note that having a non-key attribute functionally dependent on a subset of the key violates third normal form.  You would normally introduce a different table key'd by (a,b) to store any attributes that are dependent on that combination.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - as the OP has indicated, this appears to be some form of multi-step transformation process (e.g. `colD` is going to replace `colA` and `colB` later), so I'm not too worried about normalization if that's the case here.